# I want to merge some JS codes

Tags: javascript

Please, can anyone help me merging these JS codes in one working JavaScript code?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $("document").ready(function($) {
        var num = $('#nav').offset().top;
        var nav = $('#header-wrapper');
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > num) {
                nav.addClass("ffd-hdwrb");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("ffd-hdwrb");
            }
        });
    });
//]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $("document").ready(function($) {
        var num = $('#nav').offset().top;
        var nav = $('#nav');
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > num) {
                nav.addClass("ffd-nav");
                nav.removeClass("ffn-nav");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("ffd-nav");
                nav.addClass("ffn-nav");
            }
        });
    });
//]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $("document").ready(function($) {
        var num = $('#nav').offset().top;
        var nav = $('.Top-wrapper');

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > num) {
                nav.addClass("ffd-wrapper");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("ffd-wrapper");
            }
        });
    });
//]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $("document").ready(function($) {
        var num = $('#nav').offset().top;

        var nav = $('.container-wrapper, #main-nav, #main-nav ul li a');
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > num) {
                nav.addClass("ffd-all");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("ffd-all");
            }
        });
    });
//]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $("document").ready(function($) {
        var num = $('#main-nav li.search-box').offset().top;
        var nav = $('#main-nav li.search-box');
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > num) {
                nav.addClass("ffd-shrs");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("ffd-shrs");
            }
        });
    });
//]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $("document").ready(function($) {
        var num = $('#selectnav1').offset().top;
        var nav = $('#selectnav1');
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > num) {
                nav.addClass("ffd-nn11");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("ffd-nn11");
            }
        });
    });
//]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $("document").ready(function($) {
        var num = $('.selectnav').offset().top;
        var nav = $('.selectnav');

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > num) {
                nav.addClass("ffd-nn");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("ffd-nn");
            }
        });
    });
//]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $("document").ready(function($) {
        var num = $('#sidebar').offset().top;
        var nav = $('#sidebar');

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > num) {
                nav.addClass("ffd-sdbrr");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("ffd-sdbrr");
            }
        });
    });
//]]></script>
```

I think it has the same properties and merge is not impossible but I do not know JavaScript very well.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: it's **Javascript** not **Java scripts**...

Comment: remove all occurrences of and `//]]></script><script type='text/javascript'>` -et voilà
      ` -actually lose all the       `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]>` - that hasn't been needed since IE was 6 or something

Comment: If you merge all the code inside all the separate `$("document").ready(function($){` calls, you'll have issues with `num` being used over and over ... go ahead and change all the `num` to something more meaningful, or keep each `$("document").ready(function($){` as it is

Comment: I hope that not only me saw this security issue with this question, when _"if you want answer the question, you need to open external link"_.

Comment: @Egel The question have been edited for not need to open an external link

Comment: Super @YosvelQuintero, but mainly I wanted that the whole knowledge from this minor tip will go straight through the author for his future questions.

Comment: thanks guys .. sorry for the wrongs I'm new here and in javascript codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to merge it .. this is the new js code

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
$(&quot;document&quot;).ready(function($) {
var num = $(&#39;#nav&#39;).offset().top;
var numm = $(&#39;#sidebar&#39;).offset().top;
var nummm = $(&#39;#selectnav1&#39;).offset().top;
var numv = $(&#39;.selectnav&#39;).offset().top;
var nav = $(&#39;#nav&#39;);
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() &gt; num) {
$(&#39;#header-wrapper&#39;).addClass(&quot;ffd-hdwrb&quot;);
$(&#39;.Top-wrapper&#39;).addClass(&quot;ffd-wrapper&quot;);
$(&#39;.container-wrapper, #main-nav, #main-nav ul li a&#39;).addClass(&quot;ffd-all&quot;);
$(&#39;#main-nav li.search-box&#39;).addClass(&quot;ffd-shrs&quot;);
nav.addClass(&quot;ffd-nav&quot;);
nav.removeClass(&quot;ffn-nav&quot;); }
else {
$(&#39;#header-wrapper&#39;).removeClass(&quot;ffd-hdwrb&quot;);
$(&#39;.Top-wrapper&#39;).removeClass(&quot;ffd-wrapper&quot;);
$(&#39;.container-wrapper, #main-nav, #main-nav ul li a&#39;).removeClass(&quot;ffd-all&quot;);
$(&#39;#main-nav li.search-box&#39;).removeClass(&quot;ffd-shrs&quot;);
nav.removeClass(&quot;ffd-nav&quot;);
nav.addClass(&quot;ffn-nav&quot;); }
if ($(this).scrollTop() &gt; numm) {
$(&#39;#sidebar&#39;).addClass(&quot;ffd-sdbrr&quot;);
} else {
$(&#39;#sidebar&#39;).removeClass(&quot;ffd-sdbrr&quot;);
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() &gt; nummm) {
$(&#39;#selectnav1&#39;).addClass(&quot;ffd-nn11&quot;);
} else {
$(&#39;#selectnav1&#39;).removeClass(&quot;ffd-nn11&quot;);
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() &gt; numv) {
$(&#39;.selectnav&#39;).addClass(&quot;ffd-nn&quot;);
} else {
$(&#39;.selectnav&#39;).removeClass(&quot;ffd-nn&quot;);
}
});
});
</script>
```

but now I have two problems ..
-1 when I remove

```
//<![CDATA[
..
//]]>
```

the js code become With some symbols .. how I can remove it 
-2 the code show long and Complex ..  You could write code in another way for faster site ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of objects and iterate like these:

```
$('document').ready(function ($) {
    var arr = [{
        num: $('#nav').offset().top,
        nav: $('#header-wrapper'),
        fn: function (num, nav) {
            return ($(this).scrollTop() > num) ? nav.addClass('ffd-hdwrb') : nav.removeClass('ffd-hdwrb');
        }
    }, {
        num: $('#nav').offset().top,
        nav: $('#nav'),
        fn: function (num, nav) {
            return ($(this).scrollTop() > num) ? nav.addClass('ffd-nav').removeClass('ffn-nav') : nav.removeClass('ffd-nav').addClass('ffn-nav');
        }
    }, {
        num: $('#nav').offset().top,
        nav: $('.Top-wrapper'),
        fn: function (num, nav) {
            return ($(this).scrollTop() > num) ? nav.addClass('ffd-wrapper') : nav.removeClass('ffd-wrapper');
        }
    }, {
        num: $('#nav').offset().top,
        nav: $('.container-wrapper, #main-nav, #main-nav ul li a'),
        fn: function (num, nav) {
            return ($(this).scrollTop() > num) ? nav.addClass('ffd-all') : nav.removeClass('ffd-all');
        }
    }, {
        num: $('#main-nav li.search-box').offset().top,
        nav: $('#main-nav li.search-box'),
        fn: function (num, nav) {
            return ($(this).scrollTop() > num) ? nav.addClass('ffd-shrs') : nav.removeClass('ffd-shrs');
        }
    }, {
        num: $('#selectnav1').offset().top,
        nav: $('#selectnav1'),
        fn: function (num, nav) {
            return ($(this).scrollTop() > num) ? nav.addClass('ffd-nn11') : nav.removeClass('ffd-nn11');
        }
    }, {
        num: $('.selectnav').offset().top,
        nav: $('.selectnav'),
        fn: function (num, nav) {
            return ($(this).scrollTop() > num) ? nav.addClass('ffd-nn') : nav.removeClass('ffd-nn');
        }
    }, {
        num: $('#sidebar').offset().top,
        nav: $('#sidebar'),
        fn: function (num, nav) {
            return ($(this).scrollTop() > num) ? nav.addClass('ffd-sdbrr') : nav.removeClass('ffd-sdbrr');
        }
    }];

    arr.forEach(function (row) {
        $(window).scroll(row.fn(row.num, row.nav));
    });
});
```

Comment: ty for your reply .. I try this but without any effect .. I dont know what is the wrong

Comment: sorry .. I'm new in the javascript .. can you Give me any easy javascript console please